# Insert XML element with SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, xml, asp.net-core

I have a ASP.NET Core application. And I have a XML file like this:

```
<qrcode xmlns="http://vital.nl/qrcodeSchema.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Echeq>
    <echeqFamilyId>67c8590e-66fe-43e1-9124-a2163a6365df</echeqFamilyId>
  </Echeq>
</qrcode>
```

But so I want to add programmatically a other XML field to this file:

```
 <awardedVPoints></awardedVPoints>
```

So I tried like this:

```
  ;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://vital.nl/qrcodeSchema.xsd' AS ns) 
    UPDATE[dbo].[QRCodeDefinitions]     
    SET[QRCodeXml].modify('insert <ns:awardedVPoints/> as first into (/ns:qrcode)[0]')
    where [QRCodeXml].value('count(/ns:qrcode)', 'int') > 0
```

But so when I executed this I see a positive message:

```
(102 rows affected)

Completion time: 2020-06-11T11:03:16.5813475+02:00
```

But if I look in the file, I don't see the `awardedVPoints` xmlElement.

I still see this:

```
<qrcode xmlns="http://vital.nl/qrcodeSchema.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Echeq>
    <echeqFamilyId>67c8590e-66fe-43e1-9124-a2163a6365df</echeqFamilyId>
  </Echeq>
</qrcode>
```

So what I have to change?

I also try it with the old Replace like this:

```
UPDATE[dbo].[QRCodeDefinitions]     
   SET[QRCodeXml] = CAST(REPLACE(CAST([QRCodeXml] as nvarchar(max)), '<awardedVPoints/>', ' <awardedVPoints>') as xml) from [dbo].[QRCodeDefinitions]
```

So I see a success. But if I look in the xml file, I dont see any changes

I try it like this:

```
   ;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://vital.nl/qrcodeSchema.xsd' AS ns) 
    UPDATE[dbo].[QRCodeDefinitions]     
    SET[QRCodeXml].modify('insert <ns:awardedVPoints>0</ns:awardedVPoints>  as first into (/ns:qrcode)[0]')
    where [QRCodeXml].value('count(/ns:qrcode)', 'int') > 0 and qrcode = 'newvcheq'
```

(1 row affected)

but if I look in the xml there is nothing changed.

So this has to be the desired outcome:

```
<qrcode xmlns="http://vital.nl/qrcodeSchema.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Echeq>
 <awardedVPoints>0</awardedVPoints>
    <echeqFamilyId>67c8590e-66fe-43e1-9124-a2163a6365df</echeqFamilyId>
  </Echeq>
</qrcode>
```

Thank you

so this is the xsd:

```
    <xs:complexType name="echeqType">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Echeq action.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="actionVpointsBaseType">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="echeqFamilyId" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
```

So this has to be:

```
<qrcode xmlns="http://vital.nl/qrcodeSchema.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Echeq>
 <awardedVPoints>0</awardedVPoints>
    <echeqFamilyId>67c8590e-66fe-43e1-9124-a2163a6365df</echeqFamilyId>
  </Echeq>
</qrcode>
```

Comment: Try query with SQL Server Management Studio to see if it works.  The error messages are much better in SSMS

Comment: But I dont see any error. But I am using sequel server management studio V18.5

Comment: When an Update occurs and nothing gets inserted there are no errors in c#.  Using SSMS will report syntax issue like if the type is wrong.  You are not using any parameters in the query which may be the issue.  SSMS will do type checking.

Comment: @NiceTobeBottleInfinity, please edit your original post and add there your desired XML output.

Comment: I edit the post

Answer (score 0):

Try using an index of 1:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://vital.nl/qrcodeSchema.xsd' AS ns) 
    UPDATE[dbo].[QRCodeDefinitions]     
    SET [QRCodeXml].modify('insert <ns:awardedVPoints/> as first into (/ns:qrcode)[1]')
    where [QRCodeXml].value('count(/ns:qrcode)', 'int') > 0;
```

Comment: And how to get a default value for it, like 1, for example

Comment: XML Validation: Invalid content. Expected element(s):

Comment: If you mean a default for awardedVPoints, I'm no XML expert, but I would think something like 'insert <ns:awardedVPoints>1</ns:awardedVPoints> as first...'